# JUNIT Test case not passed

Tags: java, hibernate, junit

I have class where I am written code to create a new category and if category not found it will throw "CategoryNotFoundException". I have written the test cases but it was not passed.

If I omit "expected= CategoryNotFoundException.class" from my JUNIT test case it will pass. But I don't want to change any portion in my Test cases. I tried by throwing the exception from my implemented class but still it is not passed.I am stucking there to  pass the TestCase.

```
    DAO code::
    @Transactional
        public boolean createCategory(Category category){
            //boolean isInserted=false;

            Session session=this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            session.save(category);
            return true;

            //return isInserted;
        }
```

Tried with the below code as well but TC not passed:

```
   @Transactional
                public boolean createCategory(Category category){
                    //boolean isInserted=false;  
                try{            
                    Session session=this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
                    Integer isInsertedWrapper=(Integer)session.save(category);
                    if(isInsertedWrapper>0){
                      return true;
                     }else{
                       throw new CategoryNotFoundException("CategoryNotFoundException");
    }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
       return false;
    } 
}
```

JUNIT Code::

```
    @Test(expected= CategoryNotFoundException.class)
        @Rollback(true)
        public void testCreateCategoryFailure() throws CategoryNotFoundException {
            categoryDAO.createCategory(category);
            Category savedCategory = categoryDAO.getCategoryById(2);
            assertNotEquals(category, savedCategory);`enter code here`

        }
```

Comment: if the case failed then the implementation has not passed, that is, the implementation is not doing what is expected and must be changed (assuming the test is correct) In other words, your test expect an Exception being thrown, the method is not throwing any (methoeds seem to be implemented to return `false` instead of throwing an Exception - test is assuming something different)

Comment: BTW: something wrong with the whole process - you don't write a test so the test passes; you write a test to check if the implementation is doing as specified (test must be built to reflect the specification , not the implementation)

Comment: Two other things to note: You're using obsolete Hibernate interfaces (the JPA interfaces are now the recommended ones), and since you're apparently using Spring already, you might as well use Spring Data, which will automatically generate DAO classes for you.

Comment: Yeah I can use JPA but hibernate was used there.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to throw an exception but you are catching also, so you should rethrow If it is necessary, so you should try to do this:

```
@Transactional
public boolean createCategory(Category category){
                //boolean isInserted=false;  
    try {            
         Session session=this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

         Integer isInsertedWrapper=(Integer)session.save(category);

         if(isInsertedWrapper>0){
             return true;
         }else{
             throw new CategoryNotFoundException("CategoryNotFoundException");
         }
    } catch(CategoryNotFoundException exc) {
         throw exc;
    } catch(Exception ex){
         return false;
    } 
}
```

Comment: If I  throw the Exception from catch block Then I need to throws it in method signature then I need to change the DAO method which is an Interface. So I can;t change there.

Comment: Okay so you should extend from RuntimeException to CategoryNotFoundException.

Comment: same exception. Assertion error .Expected Exception in 'CategoryNotFoundException'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198450/discussion-between-jonathan-johx-and-stumbler).